# Entought Canopy Python and Pyinstaller

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pyinstaller, canopy

I am new here and to Python as well. I was doing some programming for graph interpolation, where the data is taken out of some .txt files. Here are some imported modules (and a small beggining part):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import itertools
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema 
from scipy import interpolate 


os.chdir("C:\Si_growth_calib")

is_valid = 0

while not is_valid: 
    try:
        file_x = str(raw_input("Enter your x_file name: "))
        file_y = str(raw_input("Enter your y_file name: "))

        x = np.loadtxt(file_x)
        y = np.loadtxt(file_y)
        is_valid = 1
    except ValueError:
        print("No such file, try again")
```

In Python the programme runs perfectly. After installing Pyinstall (2.1.1dev - the ordinary 2.1 did not work at all) and running it on a program I get an .exe file. After that i can only type the file names I want to import, and than i get some fast console exit, i even cannot identify the errors there... I could only capture them with screenshot option. Here they are:

```
***mk2_mc3.dll *** failed with error 126: The specified module could not be found 
***mk2_def.dll *** failed with error 126: The specified module could not be found 
MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load neither mk2_mc3.dll nor mk2_def.dll
```

Comment: Can you post some of those errors you are getting?

Comment: There errors which I have got:
***mk2_mc3.dll *** failed with error 126: The specified module could not be found

***mk2_def.dll *** failed with error 126: The specified module could not be found

MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load neither mk2_mc3.dll nor mk2_def.dll

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there are several bug reports on PyInstaller and canpoy, you can see a few if you look at the enthought bugtracker. I saw this post, and maybe this could be your issue, or at least related: [pyinstaller error: cannot find scipy (No module named _ufuncs_cxx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472683/pyinstaller-error-cannot-find-scipy-no-module-named-ufuncs-cxx)